# Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> on a math algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I've made the following pseudocode:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[H]
pseudoalgoritmo GRASP(maxIt, seed)\;
 \For{k = 1, ..., itmax }{
solucion \leftarrow faseConstructiva(seed):\;

solucion \leftarrow busquedaLocal(solucion);\;

ActualizarSolucion (solucion, mejorSolucion)\;
}
return mejorSolucion\;
\caption{Pseudoalgoritmo GRASP}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

And I'm getting the `Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>` error at the line where the `for`statement closes. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a MWE http://goo.gl/dtPzv

Comment: The symbol `\leftarrow` is really intended for math mode. That's why you're getting a ` missing $ inserted`.

Comment: What can I use then to put a left arrow symbol? Thanks in advance @1010011010

Comment: Updatd with a MWE @cornelius . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BorjaTornos `\leftarrow` -> `$\leftarrow$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How [1010011010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/44160/1010011010) user said, you must use `$\leftarrow$` instead of `\leftarrow`.

Comment: I've also another little problem. Do do you also know how can i add those `$` to this line? `\left \{ s \right \} ;\;` This makes a `{s};`. I tried `$\left \{$ s $\right \}$ ;\;` But it's not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BorjaTornos `$\left \{$ s $\right \}$` ->`$\{s\}$`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mathmode `$\leftarrow$` (as suggested in comments) can also use `\textleftarrow` from [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\begin{algorithm}[H]
pseudoalgoritmo GRASP(maxIt, seed)\;
 \For{k = 1, ..., itmax }{
solucion \textleftarrow\ faseConstructiva(seed):\;

solucion $\leftarrow$ busquedaLocal(solucion);\;

ActualizarSolucion (solucion, mejorSolucion)\;
}
return mejorSolucion\;
\caption{Pseudoalgoritmo GRASP}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]